# Assumption of commutativity in proof that a polynomial of degree $n$ can have at most $n$ roots in any extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

From Herstein's "Topics in Algebra" ($2^{\text{nd}}$ edition):

> LEMMA $5.3.2$ $\;$ *A polynomial of degree $n$ over a field can have at most $n$ roots in any extension field.*
>
> $\;$ *Proof.* $\;$ We proceed by induction on $n$, the degree of the polynomial $p(x)$. If $p(x)$ is of degree $1$, the it must be of the form $\alpha x + \beta$ where $\alpha , \beta$ are in a field $F$ and where $\alpha \neq 0$. Any $a$ such that $p(a) = 0$ must then imply that $\alpha a + \beta = 0$, from which we conclude that $a = (-\beta/\alpha)$. That is, $p(x)$ has a unique root $-\beta/\alpha$, whence the conclusion of the lemma certainly holds in this case.
>
> $\;$ Assuming the result to be true in any field for all polynomials of degree less than $n$, let us suppose that $p(x)$ is of degree $n$ over $F$. Let $K$ be any extension of $F$. If $p(x)$ has no roots in $K$, then we are certainly done, for the number of roots in $K$, namely zero, is definitely at most $n$. So, suppose that $p(x)$ has at least one root $a \in K$ and that $a$ is a root of multiplicity $m$. Since $(x-a)^{m} \mid p(x)$, $m \leq n$ follows. Now $p(x) = (x-a)^{m} q(x)$, where $q(x) \in K[x]$ is of degree $n - m$. From the fact that $(x-a)^{m+1} \not\mid p(x)$, we get that $(x-a) \not\mid q(x)$, whence, by the corollary to Lemma $5.3.1$, $a$ is not a root of $q(x)$. If $b \neq a$ is a root, in $K$, of $p(x)$, then $0 = p(b) = (b-a)^m q(b)$; however, since $b - a \neq 0$ and since we are in a field, we conclude that $q(b) = 0$. That is, any root of $p(x)$, in $K$, other than $a$, must be a root of $q(x)$. Since $q(x)$ is of degree $n-m \lt n$, by our induction hypothesis, $q(x)$ has at most $n-m$ roots in $K$, which, together with the other root $a$, counted $m$ times, tell us that $p(x)$ has at most $m + (n-m)$ roots in $K$. This completes the induction and proves the lemma.

The corollary to Lemma $5.3.1$:

> *If $a \in K$ is a root of $p(x) \in F[x]$, where $F \subset K$, then in $K[x]$, $(x-a) \mid p(x)$.

After the proof of Lemma $5.3.2$, Herstein points out that commutativity is necessary for the lemma to be true: In the ring of real quaternions, the polynomial $x^{2} + 1$ has an infinite number of roots. But where exactly is commutativity used in the proof of Lemma $5.3.2$?

Comment: Among other places, without commutativity, you don't know that $p(x)=(x-a)^mq(x).$

Comment: Just test each step of the proof with the counterexample you have given, i.e., with the  polynomial $f(x) = x^2+1$ having infinitely many roots in $\mathbb{H}[x]$. For a proof see for example [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3272522/show-that-x2-1-has-an-infinite-number-of-roots-in-q).

Comment: The Factor Theorem fails, e.g. see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1045943/242) ([unless](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3084508/242) you restrict to one-sided  polynomials)